# What is the type of function that modifies a varible in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to find out what type of function it is in JavaScript that modifies the original variable, as shown below.

```js
let array = ["a", "b", "c"]
console.log(array) // Returns: ["a", "b", "c"]
array.shift()
console.log(array) // Returns: ["b", "c"]
```

With other functions, you would normally have to do the following.

```js
let string = " String "
console.log(string) // Returns: " String "
string.trim()
console.log(string) // Returns: " String "
string = string.trim()
console.log(string) // Returns: "String"
```

How would I reproduce the same type of function?

Comment: so you want a shift that does not modify the array on which you are invoking shift?

Comment: @Berto99 no, i want to make my own function that modify the variable it is invoking, a string maybe. Any example would be helpful.

Comment: This may help: https://lorenstewart.me/2017/01/22/javascript-array-methods-mutating-vs-non-mutating/

Comment: @Berto99 ... no, OP asks for a mutating variant of `trim` similar to `shift` that mutates its array.

Comment: @jdaz Thanks! That is very helpful. But I was wondering if there was any way I could make my own?

Comment: Ah got it. You cannot modify passed variables that are primitives, like numbers or strings. You can only change arrays or objects. See this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/3638034/1174966

Comment: @jdaz This is what i was looking for. Thanks!